# Missing export named "QueryFile"

Tags: node.js, typescript, pg, pg-promise

I just tried starting to use pg-promise and ran into an error I cannot understand at all. I am kinda new to typescript in general, so it might be more of a typescript error and not a pg-promise one.

I do have the following code:

```
import {join} from "path/posix";
import {QueryFile, IQueryFileOptions} from 'pg-promise';


export const users = {
    create: sql('users/create.sql'),
    all: sql('users/all.sql')
};

function sql(file: string): QueryFile {

    const fullPath: string = join(__dirname, file); // generating full path;

    const options: IQueryFileOptions = {
        minify: true
    };

    const qf: QueryFile = new QueryFile(fullPath, options);

    if (qf.error) {
        console.log("TEst")
    }

    return qf;
}
```

When I try running it using `tsx index.ts` I do receive the following error:
 `The requested module 'pg-promise' does not provide an export named 'QueryFile'`

This is weird, because this is kind of the example code given by vitaly. My tsconfig is the following:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2020",
    "strict": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Again, its the same as in [vitaly's example](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise-demo/tree/master/TypeScript)

When trying to run it using `ts-node` it also throws an error, which might be a hint for someone more experienced than me to solve my problem?:
`TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /Users/myname/Desktop/web-api/test.ts`

Thanks for you help in advance :)

I tried 20+ different tsconfigs because I dont know if this is the root cause for this problem. I tried to run this code on another version of node (20, 18, 16...)